# SQL ID not in the table

Tags: mysql, sql

So I'm looking for a solution to check if the "ID" is in the SQL.

```
SELECT id FROM t_data WHERE partnerid=12
```

The id i will get from the logged in user.

```
<?php echo $id ?>
```

So everything works fine if there are entries with the right id in my table.
But if there are no row with this id i get an error. Is it possible to set something like if the id is not in the row do nothing?

Comment: You don't get an error if there is no id.  You get an empty result set.

Comment: Did you try putting the ID number in single quotes? `'12'`

Comment: Oh. You are right. Oky it works. I tested it with an logged in user and the error is the result when i tried do to that when I'm not logged in. Cause than i don't get a ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following:

```
  select IFNULL(id,'') FROM t_data WHERE partnerid=12
```

or you can use

```
select if(id is not null, id ,'')  FROM t_data WHERE partnerid=12
```